# SSH connection refused/error message

Tags: server, ssh, login

I have a setup of systems, where each system has multiple users but only one user is allowed to login to a system at a time through SSH.

I am using "passwd  -l/-u" command to lock and unlock users, and allow only one user at a time.

What I need is to tell the other users trying to SSH to a system why they cannot SSH. Currently when the user account is locked and they cannot SSH they only get "Connection Refused" message. I want to be able to edit this message to tell them "Your account is locked and you cannot login before xxxxxxx time"

What are the possible ways I can achieve this. I have tried googling for this but without any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this inside SSH, and in order to display such a message, you would have to let them log in first, then have bash tell them why they 'cant' log in and then log them out.

Comment: @Daniel : ok, I will try the approach you suggested. BTW do you mean we cannot change the "Connection Refused" message at all , to any custom message in any scenario ?

Comment: You could download the `ssh` and `sshd` sources, make any changes you like, and use the modified versions. When a newer version of `ssh` or `sshd` is released, you would have to reapply your changes, or stay with your old, customized version. A **Bad Idea**.

Comment: I found a better solution to my needs. 
To re-enable the user to /usr/bin/nologin where I can display them a message from /etc/nologin.txt. And when I want to activate then I can change their shell back to /bin/bash. I could use usermod command to do this from a script.

Comment: ^ That works!  super!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the message but not per-user you can use `nologin`, meaning re-enabling users account but assigning them `/usr/bin/nologin` as their login shell. They will not be able to connect and receive a default message saying the account is disabled or the message written in `/etc/nologin.txt`.

If you want a per-user message you can replace `nologin` with a hand-made script which always returns 1.

From https://serverfault.com/a/708923/186199 where is dupplicate marked as solved. Please mark it so here.